# How can I implement partial classes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, partial-classes

How can I implement partial classes in JavaScript?

For example, I have a class like this:

```
function MyClass(){
    this.myName = "I am native member";
};

myObj = new MyClass();
console.log(myObj.myName); // Will print "I am native member"
```

I want some properties of this class to be declared somewhere else in another piece of code, possibly in another file. I can extend `myObj` easily in JavaScript, but only `myObj` is affected, not other instances of `MyClass`.  I want new instances of the class to include all definitions from the partial extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from this code snippet:

```
function MyClass(){
    this.myName = "I am native member";
    for (var key in MyClass.Partial) {
        MyClass.Partial[key].apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
MyClass.Partial = {};
```

If I want to extend the class somewhere else, I can write:

```
MyClass.Partial.Def1 = function(){ 
   /* here Def1 is just a meaningful name. 
      It has no impact on MyClass access behavior 
   */
    this.myLastName = "I am partial member";
};

myObj = new MyClass();
console.log(myObj.myName); // Will print "I am native member"
console.log(myObj.myLastName); // Will print "I am partial member"
```